# Error code 3 , -1073741819 & -1073741510

Tags: qt, error-code, qt5.4

Running my app gives me Error Code 3 , -1073741819 and -1073741510
Why these codes come generally ???
I mean what cause them to send themselves to the debugger ?
I tried to work with a file using QFile in the Qt Framework.
My code is the following (notice that is a very low-power antivirus solution) :

```
QFile VirusScanner(Current);
while(!VirusScanner.atEnd()) {
    QByteArray Line = VirusScanner.readLine(LONG_LONG_MAX);
    if(Line.toLower() == "open=regsvr.exe" || Line.toLower() == "open=newfolder.exe") {
        cout << "Autorun.inf virus detected. Deleteing..." << std::endl;
        const QString Virus_Path = VirusScanner.fileName();
        VirusScanner.close();
        QFile::remove();
    }
}
```

After Vahancho's comment i changed the code to the following but it gave me the -1073741510 error code :

```
QFile VirusScanner(Current);
VirusScanner.open(stdin , QFile::ReadOnly);
while(!VirusScanner.atEnd()) {
    QByteArray Line = VirusScanner.readLine(LONG_LONG_MAX);
    if(Line.toLower() == "open=regsvr.exe" || Line.toLower() == "open=newfolder.exe") {
        cout << "Autorun.inf virus detected. Deleteing..." << std::endl;
        VirusScanner.remove();
    }
} 
VirusScanner.close();
```

Comment: Don't you need to open the `VirusScanner` file? Don't you need to exit your loop and stop reading the file you have already deleted?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `QTextStream` to take care of conversion, new-line characters, etc... So also your *if statement* works as expected.

Also, you shouldn't open `stdin` if you want to read from `Current` file.

Given that, this would work:

```
QString current = "some_file";
bool bHasVirus = false;

QFile virusScanner(current);
if (!virusScanner.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)) {
    return -1;
}

QTextStream in(&virusScanner);
while(!in.atEnd()) {
    QString line = in.readLine();
    qDebug() << line.toLower();
    if(line.toLower() == "open=regsvr.exe" || line.toLower() == "open=newfolder.exe") {
        // Virus detected!
        bHasVirus = true;
        break;
    }
}

if(bHasVirus) {
    qDebug() << "Virus detected. Deleteing...";
    virusScanner.remove(); // Will also close the file
} else {
    virusScanner.close();
}
```

Note: Capital letters are usually for *Classes*, not *variables*.